# Filter entries by ajax to controller

Tags: ajax, filter, controller

Short story: I need your help sending value from dropdown selection as data to controller so my div updates with the filtered entries based on the selection.

Long story and code: I have a listing of entries in my template as follows:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('live').find() %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I know I can filter those results with a field handle by updating the first line above with:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('live').hostSite('weDo').find() %}
```

However I'd like to filter that listing of entries with a dropdown list that contains the available field handles, ie 'weDo, 'theyDo':

```
<select class="filter">
    <option value="all">all sites</option>
    <option value="weDo">sites we host</option>
    <option value="theyDo">sites they host</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to do this with Ajax and a controller I set up:

```
**Javascript**
// Add an event listener for filter clicks
$(function () {
    $('body').on('change', 'select.filter', onFilterClick);
});

// Event handler for the filter click
function onFilterClick (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = this.value;

    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'actions/websiteListing/checkStatus',
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        $('.livelisting').html(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('error', data);
    }); 
}
**Controller**
<?php
namespace Craft;

class WebsiteListingController extends BaseController
{
    protected $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionCheckStatus()
    {
        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
        $criteria->section('live');
        $criteria->hostSite = 'weDo';
        $criteria->limit = null;

        $entries = $criteria->find();

        foreach ($criteria as $entry) {
            echo $entry->title . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

I know the ajax is pretty trashy, but the url to the controller file is working correctly because when I make a selection from the dropdown menu, my div.livelisting is replaced by the single entry available with the field handle of 'weDo'.

**Here's where your help is needed!** The 'weDo' value in my controller needs the data sent from Ajax. Thanks for your expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little more research on Ajax and found a solution. I updated my Ajax such that the data line looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'actions/websiteListing/checkStatus',
    data: {filter: data},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Then in my controller, I was able to pass that data by adding $filter to the first line and including that for my 3rd $criteria line:

```
public function actionCheckStatus($filter)
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = ('live');
    $criteria->hostSite = $filter;
    $criteria->limit = null;

    $entries = $criteria->find();

    foreach ($criteria as $entry) {
        echo $entry->title . '<br>';
    }
    die();
}
```